# Youtube autoplay on website

Tags: youtube, embed

I am trying to find a way to have a youtube link automatically start playing when a user enters the site.  Does anyone know how to do this.  I have read something about using autoplay in the link.  Here is the link to embed on my page.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kttooVrewF8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what your link should look like.  Just put autoplay=1 after the url.  You may also try putting ?autoplay=1 after.  Hope this helps.  Live Long and Prosper.